# Store hourly data efficient way

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database-design

There is a requirement to store hourly data in SQL Server 2016 and retrieve. It's an OLTP database.

I will explain with an example: we need to capture temperature of each city of a country and store on hourly basis. What would be the best and efficient design to do this. The data would be stored for a year and then archived

This is my plan. Can some one review and let me know if this approach is fine?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CityMaster]
(
    [CityId] [int] NULL,
    [CityName] [varchar](300) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

--OPTION 1
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeatherData]
(
    [Id] [bigint] NULL,
    [CityId] [int] NULL,
    [HrlyTemp] [decimal](18, 1) NULL,
    [CapturedTIme] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--OPTION2
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeatherData_JSon] 
(
    [Id] [bigint] NULL,
    [CityId] [int] NULL,
    [Month] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Hrlytemp] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Use `datetime2` not `datetime`. Not sure where you were going with the JSON, but avoid it if you can, its not relational and will perform badly trying to extract data from lots of JSON rows.

Comment: `[HrlyTemp] [decimal](18, 1)` You just are not thinking about your datatypes at all. You wish to store a max temp of 99999999999999999.9? Or as `[Hrlytemp] [nvarchar](max)` a giant string? All your columns are nullable? Where is your primary key? Start over and THINK this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To some extent, this depends on how the data is going to be used.  The most natural solution is to tweak the first option and use a partitioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].CityHourlyTemperatures (
    Id bigint NULL,
    CityId int NULL,
    HrlyTemp decimal(6, 1) NULL,
    CapturedTIme datetime NULL
) ;
```

Note I changed the name to something that seems to better capture the name.

Even with global warming, I think that 4 or 5 digits of precision in the temperature is quite sufficient -- 18 is way overkill.

Each row here has 8 + 4 + 5 + 8 bytes = 25 bytes (it may be rounded up if there are alignment restrictions).  A year has about 8,766 hours.  So, if you have 100 cities, this is less than a million rows per year and just a few tens of megabytes per year.

That is quite feasible, but you might want to consider partitioning the table -- the older partitions can act like an "archive".

Your second option stores the temperatures as a blob.  This would make sense under only one circumstance:  you don't care about the temperatures but you need to return the data to an application that does.

The implication from the name is that you want to store the value as JSON.  This usually requires *more* overhead than storing the data using native types -- and is often less efficient.  JSON is very powerful and useful for some types of data, particularly sparse data.  However, your data is quite relational and can be stored in a relational format.

If you wanted to save space, you could consider the following:

- Replacing the `datetime` value with an `hourId` column.  This could possibly be a shortint if you only want a few years of data.
- Removing the `id` column and defining the `cityid`/`hourid` as the primary key.

However, your volume of data does not seem to suggest that such an approach is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is not feasible.
Option 1 is better.

I think `HrlyTemp` column's size should be `[decimal](4, 1)` or `[decimal](5, 1)` max.

If you deal with all the world's cities data, based on an approximation of total cities in the world ~1000.

Then you need to store `365*24*1000 = 8,760,000 ~ 9M` rows per year. To stay on the safe side, we can assume that we have to store `10M` data.

Which is OK for the SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeatherData]
(
    [Id] [bigint] NULL,
    [CityId] [int] NULL,
    [HrlyTemp] [decimal](18, 1) NULL,
    [CapturedTIme] [datetime] NULL,
    [DailyTempRepo] nvarchar(max) * record create and update per day
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
* you can normalize more your table.

how to store data in DailyTempRepo column as json :

[{"TempDate":"2021-03-06","CityId":"2","CapturedTIme":"09:30","HrlyTemp":"70"},
{"TempDate":"2021-03-06","CityId":"2","CapturedTIme":"10:30","HrlyTemp":"78"},
{"TempDate":"2021-03-06","CityId":"2","CapturedTIme":"11:30","HrlyTemp":"81"}]
```